# angular - What does ... interface Type<T> extends Function { new (...args: any[]): T; } ... mean?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Interface Type<T> is an interface which is extending global type Function. I found this in typescript documentation [Function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function) about global function.

What does the above code mean? I got this code from angular source code.

```
export const Type = Function;
```

```
export function isType(v: any): v is Type<any> {return typeof v === 'function';}
```

```
export interface Type<T> extends Function { new (...args: any[]): T; }
```

I went through Typescript documentation but not able to figure it out.

Comment: It means that a `Type<T>` is a `Function` which is also known to be a constructor for instances of type `T`.  So if you have `declare const f: Type<Date>`, then `f` is a `Function` (and has all `Function`'s properties like `length` and `bind`), but it is also a constructor for `Date` objects so you can write `new f()` and get a `Date`.  Honestly I don't know this would be necessary though, since any constructor object *automatically* inherits from `Function` without needing to declare that.  So `interface Type<T> { new (...args: any[]): T }` would behave identically.

Comment: See prev comment; dos that fully address your question? If so I'll write it up as an answer post with documentation links and examples.  If not, what am I missing?  (Also, what does this question have to do with "dependency injection"?  It doesn't appear to mention it anywhere except in the tag)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. It does answers my question. I came across this code while going through DI. So added the tag.

Comment: I'll write up an answer.  Note that "I came across this code while doing X" doesn't mean the question has anything to do with "X".  Otherwise I'd probably tag "coding" or "refactoring" or "breakfast" everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition

```
interface Type<T> extends Function { new (...args: any[]): T; }
```

means that a value of type `Type<T>` is a function which is also known to be a *constructor* for instances of type `T`.  Since it [extends](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) the  [`Function` interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function) it is a `Function`, and the syntax `{ new (⋯): ⋯ }` is a [*construct signature*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures), so it's also a constructor.

That means if you have

```
declare const f: Type<Date>;
```

then `f` is a `Function` and has all `Function`'s properties like length and bind:

```
f.apply; // okay
f.call; // okay
f.bind; // okay
f.length; // okay
```

but it is also a constructor for `Date` objects:

```
const d = new f();
//    ^? const d: Date;
```

---

That being said, I don't know why it's defined this way.  All constructor types automatically inherit from `Function`; you don't need to declare it.  You can only use [the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) on functions anyway... [`class`es](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are just special functions:

```
class Foo {}; 
console.log(typeof Foo) // "function"
```

That means the definition

```
interface Type<T> { new(...args: any[]): T; }
```

behaves the same as your version.  Perhaps it's defined this way to make the relationship with `Function` explicit?  Not sure.  But that's out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEA8qB8yA9AFTIQAekIAJgM7IBiAriAmMAPYjIlHIBvZCAgB3ABQA6aXCgBzOgC5kcEOgDaAXQCUy1AG5kAXwBQJhNzphkMPVlwAROJEIBeZE8j6zMSXEyYADbohkT8nADWcOgmvghwgYGh4VExvgBGoDTJyJHRsZKBECByYAAWOXkx5pbWNMjuIqI24treYcidyAB6APzIFiBWyDTKnhDe5oFwdAyMnJyCxt6DdJxFhZxy4mD2nDBMC9rE-ABEMKzsXCCnQA)